# How can I deserialize java.time.LocalDate in Spring HATEOAS?

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-hateoas, jsr310

I am building a Spring HATEOAS application. When I POST a JSON document containing ISO8601 dates I get:

> Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Text '2016-05-13T21:00:00.000Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10 (through reference chain: com.my.package.web.resources.MyResource["startDate"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Text '2016-05-13T21:00:00.000Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10 (through reference chain: com.my.package.web.resources.MyResource["startDate"])

I have jackson-datatype-jsr310 in my classpath as suggested [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#jackson-modules). I have also tried explicitly declaring `@JsonDeserialize`/`@JsonSerialize` on the appropriate fields using default and custom deserializers. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried providing Spring with an ObjectMapper with the JavaTimeModule registered?  I think that should do the same thing as your properly placed @JsonDeserialize/@JsonSerialize annotations, but it applies it globally and may help Spring handle this somehow (though tbh I'd be surprised if it did - it should be functionally equivalent to those annotations)

Comment: @pedorro I tried registering an ObjectMapper and setting m.deserializerByType(LocalDate.class, LocalDateDeserializer.INSTANCE) with no luck.

Comment: What about `mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());` That should handle all jsr310 types implicitly.

Comment: `2016-05-13T21:00:00.000Z` isn't a local date, is it?

Comment: No it's a string. I think [LocalDateDeserializer](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/LocalDateDeserializer.java#L72) takes into account this format. Am I mistaken? I also wrote a custom deserializer that converts from long but doesn't seem to be used at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Turns out my jackson-dataype-jsr310 was a bit old (2.6.4) and the "Z" in the date created the problem. Using the latest version of the lib (2.7.3) fixes the problem.